# Scroll View Alignment Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Can anyone help me out I can not seem to remove the white below the navigation bar as shown in the image below?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8egd3i7vyqxc9w/IMG_2015-10-31%2000%3A10%3A14.jpg?dl=0

I have other view controllers that are using the same restraints and do not have this issue?

Comment: so, when you scroll down a bit, where did you see the scroll bar ? right below the white or right side of the blue ? or right from the top of the white ?

Comment: at the top of the blue

Comment: if the scroll bar is right at the point of where blue view started, then there is nothing wrong with your scroll view. May be it is pushed down by some constraints. Can you post the screenshot of the view debugger ?

Comment: You will have to excuse me I am a newbie and not sure how to access the view debugger. Can you explain please so I can screenshot.

Comment: go through this for view debugging: http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Comment: when u run the app either on device/simulator, you have to press the view debugger option in Xcode which will show you the views of the app in realtime

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3iw8f3pey8n3a54/814419261_709294714156087715.jpg?dl=0

Comment: can u pls provide the screenshot, by turning the view a little right in the view debugger ? Also highlight the scrollview and see if it is really under the navigation bar or not

Comment: as far as i can see from the pic, the scroll view is pushed down. Did u set any constraints to your view ?

Comment: Would you mind screen sharing via team viewer?

Comment: sure....tell me your id and passcode

Comment: Could you give image from storyboard or include your code. Or more detail how you create this screen ( by code or from main screen ). Then we can get where problem come from.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Select your Controller in storyboard --> Go to Attribute Inspector --> Uncheck "Adjust scroll View Insets" in View Controller Layout Property.

See attached image.